# "There are currently logged in users who may lose unsaved changes if you restart this computer" on OS X - skip this message

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have 2 accounts, both admin, on my Mac OS X 10.6 MacBook Pro.  I use fast user switching and automatic login.  Both accounts have no password.  Security is not an issue.

It's irritating that whenever I go to restart the computer (frequently, dualboot every night to play games), I get the message prompt:

"There are currently logged in users who may lose unsaved changes if you restart this computer"

And I have to enter one of the user names and hit enter.  How can I prevent this message from occurring and simply reboot without that?  I know I can log one of the users off, but that's yet another step..

Answer (score 1):

Log out users after a certain time limit:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100604123854198

---

EDIT:

Alternatively, create an executable shell script with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "password" | sudo -S shutdown -r now
```

You could link this to an alias on your desktop.

The `-S` switch takes input from `stdin`, which is your root password as indicated above.

---

If you don't feel comfortable putting the root password in clear text, you could use `visudo` as outlined [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021202054815892).

Comment: But I switch the users frequently up until the point that I want to restart

Comment: See my revised answer with script.

Comment: I had no idea a sudo request was what made the window pop up.  That's excellentt - will try this tonight, thank you

Comment: The shell script works yes, but having a shell script to reboot my mac isn't exactly ideal - still looking for a solution to the proper reboot dialog to work

Comment: Good luck with that. You won't find anything. You're asking for a way to bypass the root password.

Comment: But what launches that window that pops up and asks me to enter a password of an administrator?  If it's something in userland I imagine I could replace the binary with something that just returns what the calling program (kernel?) is expecting?  Perhaps it goes deep enough that it's just impossible

Comment: It's deep, @Nektarios. You're talking about the fundamental possibility of deleting unsaved data belonging to another user. That needs super user rights, just like on Windows (even if it is just to click "Yes" on XP / 2003).